# Darknet and Data Augmentation

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, darknet, data-augmentation

In the darknet deep learning framework `.cfg` files we see parameters like

```
angle, saturation, exposure
```

These parameters are used for data augmentation in classic image classification problems.
Does Darknet automatically perform image augmentation automatically for object detection by setting up these parameters?

Comment: Please keep the tag spam to a minimum. This plainly isn't a question which has *anything* to do with CUDA, so don't tag as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. By default, data augmentation is done automatically by DarkNet. For example, when training, the input image will be rotated by a random angle, up to the specified angle. With those parameters in the .cfg file, you can control thoses limits.

Comment: Do you have any resource or link for an article speaking about this ?

Comment: From the DarkNet github project: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/wiki/CFG-Parameters-in-the-%5Bnet%5D-section, there is an explanation of the parameters.

Comment: What is the parameter used to scale images during augmentation. I don't see it in the link  .

Comment: The min_crop and max_crop parameters are applied for classification, but not for detection.

Comment: That is not true, parameters like "angle" in the .cfg file are not used during object detection training.